# How to fill FAT32 file system(linux) easily? My device drive is 32GB, in which 5 GB space will be taken for OS

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, filesystems, fat32

I'm using 32GB device(linux based), which is using FAT32 filesystem, i want to test one thing that what would be the device behavior when i fill the device space with some random files.

normally side loading the contents will take more than a day to fill the device.

it would be better to create junk files via shell script to fill the empty space. can anyone help me in this?

I don't want use the below commands. In my case i want create actual files.

```
fallocate -l 50G big_file
truncate -s 50G big_file
dd of=bigfile bs=1 seek=50G count=0
```

Comment: Since FAT32 doesn't support sparse files there would be little wrong with `fallocate`. Maybe in a loop rather than as a single lump, though.

Comment: Isn't FAT32 supposed not to be able to have file over 4GB?

Answer (score 0):

try dd command from /dev/urandom something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/<path_to_file> bs=2048 conv=noerror,sync count=999999
```

Comment: Hi thanks lot, do you have any manual/document to know more about this?

Comment: I tired in my device, that command is not working and shows usage of dd.

Comment: @Santhosh, I think it might work for this test to fill the partition with a file containing zeros, so you can use `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=path/blank bs=4096` . It might be faster.